# Java HTTP response code 200, while it should be 301

Tags: java, http-response-codes

The following code is driving me insane.  It sometimes returns the wrong response code and I do not understand why.  E.g., `http://www.ebay.com/itm/131709867498` returns a `301 Moved Permanently` in real life (Chrome and Edge), while the following code returns `200`.  Thanks a ton in advance.  (In case it matters, I am running Java 1.8.0_66.)

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://www.ebay.com/itm/131709867498").openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(statusCode);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using "Head" method but Browsers use "GET" method, if you change

```
connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
```

TO

```
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

you will see 301 status code

Comment: I chose to use `HEAD` to receive only the header without the body, as I am only interested in the status code and not the content of the page.  How come `HEAD` gets treated differently by the server?

Comment: It's responsibility of the server, Server even can refuse one method and accept the other, so yes that's possible. They can even treat differently based on the client agent.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your URL in Curl I get a '200'.  Why do you think it should be returning 301?

```
url -I "http://www.ebay.com/itm/131709867498"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-EBAY-C-REQUEST-ID: ri=yGq%2BS7ChLgXP,rci=XOZjR%2BAfGDb5BkY5
RlogId: t6ulcpjqcj9%3Feog4d71f%2B66%600-15436278e5c-0x17a
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 0
Server: Server
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 00:10:42 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=4694AD028535546045A4E2853D7F8B72; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: ebay=%5Esbf%3D%23%5E;Domain=.ebay.com;Path=/
Set-Cookie: dp1=bu1p/QEBfX0BAX19AQA**58f94e02^bl/US5ada8182^;Domain=.ebay.com;Expires=Sat, 21-Apr-2018 00:10:42 GMT;Path=/
Set-Cookie: s=CgAD4ACBXGWwCMzYyNzhlNTcxNTQwYTYyMjg3MDFkNTExZmZiN2MyMGKrI6lP;Domain=.ebay.com;Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: nonsession=CgADLAAFXGCGKMQDKACBgfhwCMzYyNzhlNTcxNTQwYTYyMjg3MDFkNTExZmZiN2MyMGIcCAX2;Domain=.ebay.com;Expires=Fri, 21-Apr-2017 00:10:42 GMT;Path=/
```

Comment: Is it possible that Chrome and IE both get 301, while curl and Java receives a 200?

Comment: The answer to your question:  Chrome's header reads
`Request URL:http://www.ebay.com/itm/131709867498`, `Request Method:GET`, `Status Code:301 Moved Permanently`